# Change column values into strings

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

For example, I have a dataframe:

```
df

    category                              name
0   [['Clothing & Jewelry', 'Shoes']]     Jason
1   [['Clothing & Jewelry', 'Jewelry']]   Molly
```

How can I store a string of the `category` column using commas to separate the entries?

The result I would like to have:

```
    category                              name
0   Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes             Jason
1   Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry           Molly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `apply` with a `lambda`:

```
In [21]:
df['category'].apply(lambda x: x.remove('Clothing & Jewelry'))
df

Out[21]:
    category   name
0    [Shoes]  Jason
1  [Jewelry]  Molly
```

Note that storing non-scalar values in a Series is problematic as filtering and vectorised operations will not work, it would be better to store a string using commas to separate the entries

**EDIT**

To answer your updated question, I'd store the data elements in separate rows as this makes filtering easier:

```
In [79]:
df['category'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[0])).str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)

Out[79]:
   level_0                   0
0        0  Clothing & Jewelry
1        0               Shoes
2        1  Clothing & Jewelry
3        1             Jewelry
```

We can then `merge` this back to your original df and then we can filter:

```
In[80]:
df.merge(df['category'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[0])).str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1), left_index=True, right_on='level_0', how='left')

Out[80]:
                          category   name  level_0                   0
0    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason        0  Clothing & Jewelry
1    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason        0               Shoes
2  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly        1  Clothing & Jewelry
3  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly        1             Jewelry

In [82]:
df = df.drop('level_0', axis=1)
df

Out[82]:
                          category   name                   0
0    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason  Clothing & Jewelry
1    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason               Shoes
2  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly  Clothing & Jewelry
3  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly             Jewelry

In [84]:    
df.rename(columns={0:'category_values'},inplace=True)
df

Out[84]:
                          category   name     category_values
0    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason  Clothing & Jewelry
1    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason               Shoes
2  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly  Clothing & Jewelry
3  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly             Jewelry

In [85]:
df[df['category_values']!='Clothing & Jewelry']

Out[85]:
                          category   name category_values
1    [[Clothing & Jewelry, Shoes]]  Jason           Shoes
3  [[Clothing & Jewelry, Jewelry]]  Molly         Jewelry
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'` I've got this error :(

Comment: Do you suggest to change `category` column into strings? Did I understand correctly? (Sorry, I'm a beginner)

Comment: IMO yes, then you can just do `df['category'].str.replace('Clothing & Jewelry','')` or you can duplicate the entries so each entry is a separate row and then filter them out. Having the data in a single row makes filtering difficult and doesn't scale well. So in this case there would be 2 entries each for each person with the data on separate rows

Comment: Can you give some hints how to do that?

Comment: Where did your data come from?

Comment: It's just an example. The real data is similar to this, but big.

Comment: My point is that you need to create the df in the form I suggested, doing it afterwards maybe more work, so did this data come from a csv or are you populating it like this?

Comment: The data came from a csv just like this.

Comment: Edit your question with a few sample lines

Comment: Try this: `df.merge(df['category'].apply(','.join).str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1), left_index=True, right_on='level_0', how='left')` this will merge back with your df the expanded elements of your list data

Comment: Your df shows a list of lists which is different to when it was just a list do which is it?

Comment: When I opened df in jupyter notebook, it was just like that `[['Clothing & Jewelry', 'Shoes']]`

Comment: Sorry had to cook, eat and feed my family. Try this: `df.merge(df['category'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[0])).str.split(',',expand=True).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1), left_index=True, right_on='level_0', how='left')`

Comment: Thank you for your help, EdChum!